# Eclipse/Maven Project: Couldn't resolve dependencies while running Maven Install

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, maven-dependency

I have created a Maven Project to run my automation scripts using selenium+Java. I have downloaded required dependencies and when I try to run Maven install from Eclipse. I see below error. Kindly suggest where is the issue. Please find below pom file.

> Error - Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   SampleGrp:SampleArtifactID:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect
>   dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test),
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.53.0 (compile),
>   info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.4 (test),
>   info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.4 (test),
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 (compile),
>   com.aventstack:extentreports:jar:3.0.6 (provided),
>   com.vimalselvam:cucumber-extentsreport:jar:3.0.1 (compile),
>   org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.23 (compile),
>   org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.2.2 (compile),
>   commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 (compile),
>   ojdbc14:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.3.0 (compile),
>   org.jenkins-ci.plugins:scm-api:jar:1.1 (compile),
>   org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-job:jar:2.1 (test),
>   org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-support:jar:2.2 (test),
>   org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:jar:2.2 (compile),
>   org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-2 (compile),
>   org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:1.0-beta-2 (compile),
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 (compile)]: Failed
>   to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:jar:2.2: Failure to
>   find org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:2.5 in
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>SampleGrp</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleArtifactID</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>SampleArtifactID</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> 
 <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
 <version>2.53.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
 <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.4</version> 
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency> 
 <dependency> 
 <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
 <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> 
 <version>1.2.4</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency> 
 
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
 
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


 
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
 
 
<dependency>
    <groupId>ojdbc14</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>scm-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>workflow-job</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>workflow-support</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>workflow-step-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-file</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
      
    
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Why do you have all these plugins like maven-clean-plugin, maven-resources-plugin as dependencies? Furthermore Why do you have dependencies of jenkins in your pom ? Are you trying to build a jenkins plugin? If so you need to have configured other repositories...

Comment: Please post a *readable* log of `mvn -X clean install`.
It can be a lot of things. For instance, you may be behind a corporate proxy. Or there was an earlier attempt and local repo cached a lot of 404s (try cleaning up the local repo).

Comment: Yeah i was behind proxy and adding proxy details solved the issue.